# Android TCP server that maps data to an object and sends it to a service

Tags: java, android, socket

This is a code for an android thread. This is a tcp server and gets data from socket, maps it to an object and sends that object back to the main service. If there is anything I'm doing wrong or if something can be done better, I would really appreciate comments.

```
public class SocketManager extends Thread {

    Handler mHandlerThread;
    private final int MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 2048;
    private final int PORT = 2500;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private DataInputStream in = null;
    private DataOutputStream out = null;
    private GPSFields gps;
    private ObjectMapper mObjectMapper;
    private final String APPNAME = "My App";

    public SocketManager(Handler mHandlerThread) {
        this.mHandlerThread = mHandlerThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int messageLength = 0;
        gps = new GPSFields();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
        mObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        try {
            openSocket();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(APPNAME, e.toString());
        }

        while(true) {
            try {
                if(socket.isClosed()) {
                    openSocket();
                }
                else {
                    messageLength = in.readShort();
                    if (messageLength > 0 && messageLength < MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
                        in.read(buffer, 0, messageLength);
                        gps = mObjectMapper.readValue(new String(buffer), GPSFields.class);
                        if (gps != null) {
                            out.write(1);
                            Message message = new Message();
                            message.obj = gps;
                            mHandlerThread.sendMessage(message);
                            Log.d(APPNAME, "Received Latitude: " + gps.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + gps.getLongitude());
                        } else {
                            out.write(0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        out.write(0);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                closeSocket();
                Log.d(APPNAME, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeSocket() {
        try {
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(APPNAME, e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void openSocket() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            socket = new Socket();
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(APPNAME, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: What's `ObjectMapper`? Please provide more context for this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When `messageLength` happens to be too large the code just loops around to the next `messageLength = in.readShort();`. However, the message body is still there, and `readShort` will pull the short from it. Chances are, it would be interpreted as a valid message length, and the stream gets irrecoverably out of sync.

  You must discard the entire message by reading it.
- `DataInputStream.read()` hey return less bytes than requested. Yet again, the stream gets out of sync. You must read the message body in the loop, until it is consumed entirely.
- Closing the server socket every time a data socket fails seems drastic. There is nothing wrong with the server socket, and could be reused. It may need to be reopened only if `accept` fails.
- I recommend to move `openSocket` call to the exception clause:

  ```
      while (True) {
          try {
              messageLength = in.readShort();
              ....
          } catch(Exception e) {
              closeSocket();
              Log.d(APPNAME, e.toString());
              openSocket();
          }
  ```

  One nesting level down.
- You may want to be more precise about exceptions. It is very well possible that the exception has nothing to do with the socket (e.g. may `sendMessage` throw? was it a keyboard interrupt? `ObjectMapper` throw? something else? It is impossible to tell from the given code). In such cases different recovery is necessary, but the socket should likely remain intact.